# Neo4j cypher queries for Twitter clone (social graph of users)

Tags: neo4j

I am developing a Twitter clone, and need help with some Cypher queries that I need to do, based on the sample image of the graph database where I store the relationships between the users:

[image]

- Get the social graph of a user ("Following", "Followers" and the intersection of both results - "Mutuals")

I tried this an entire day (this query is syntactically correct, but with certain values of "id" parameter, the result shown was not what was expected):

`OPTIONAL MATCH (user:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(following:User) WHERE user.Id = "id" OPTIONAL MATCH (user:User)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(follower:User) WHERE user.Id = "id" RETURN user, collect(following) as Following, collect(follower) as Follower`

- Get follow suggestions, including:

  - users followed by people I follow, that **don't follow me either** (I also need to know which users that I follow follow each suggestion found - to display "followed by user1, user2 and x others" on my app)
  - users that **follow me** but I don't follow them back

I tried this so far:

`OPTIONAL MATCH (user:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(suggestion:User) WHERE NOT (user)<-[:FOLLOWS]->(suggestion) AND WHERE user.Id = "id" OPTIONAL MATCH (user:User)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(followBackSuggestion:User) WHERE NOT (user)-[:FOLLOWS]->(followBackSuggestion) AND WHERE user.Id = "id" RETURN collect(suggestion) AS MyFriendsFollow, collect(followBackSuggestion) AS FollowBack`

Comment: please show us your sample result and highlight what is not correct on your result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you MATCH (user:User) you will add more optional matches; you can't use (user:User) as this will introduce a new user variable and forgets the old one. Just use (user) to continue working with the same variable.

For this reason, always be aware of when to use Labels (for new variables) and when not.

As an example, this should work:

```
MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.Id = "id"
// with the SAME user we will perform the next statements
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:FOLLOWS]->(following:User)  
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(follower:User) 
WITH user, collect(following) as Following, collect(follower) as Follower
RETURN *
```

For the second part, I would do it like this. I also would recommend to collect data as early as possible to prevent cartensian products (of follower x following).

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (user:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(suggestion:User) 
WHERE user.Id = "id"  AND NOT EXISTS ((user)<-[:FOLLOWS]->(suggestion))
WITH user, collect(suggestion) AS MyFriendsFollow

OPTIONAL MATCH (user)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(followBackSuggestion:User) 
WHERE NOT (user)-[:FOLLOWS]->(followBackSuggestion) 
WITH user, MyFriendsFollow, collect(followBackSuggestion) AS FollowBack

RETURN *
```

This answer may not cover the issue in full, but it will solve a basic problem in your queries.

Best,
Reiner